# Rails Server exiting even after bundle install

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to run the `depot_a` rails3.1.0 example from the book "Agile Web Development with Rails 4th edition" that can be downloaded [here](http://pragprog.com/titles/rails4/source_code).

I am getting various errors I can't decipher even after running `bundle install` before calling `rails server`. Any idea how to fix this?

Thanks.

```
Your bundle is complete! Use `bundle show [gemname]` to see where a bundled gem is installed.    
nuno@Houdini:~/workspace/depot_a$ rails server
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 3.1.0 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3000
=> Call with -d to detach
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
Exiting
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:234:in `load': /home/nuno/workspace/depot_a/config/initializers/session_store.rb:11: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting $end (SyntaxError)
...sion_store :cookie_store, key: '_depot_session'
                              ^
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:234:in `load'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:223:in `load_dependency'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:640:in `new_constants_in'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:223:in `load_dependency'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:234:in `load'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.1.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:555
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.1.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:554:in `each'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.1.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:554
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.1.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:25:in `instance_exec'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.1.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:25:in `run'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.1.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:50:in `run_initializers'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.1.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:49:in `each'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.1.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:49:in `run_initializers'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.1.0/lib/rails/application.rb:92:in `initialize!'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.1.0/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `send'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.1.0/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
    from /home/nuno/workspace/depot_a/config/environment.rb:13
    from /home/nuno/workspace/depot_a/config.ru:4:in `require'
    from /home/nuno/workspace/depot_a/config.ru:4
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.3.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `instance_eval'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.3.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `initialize'
    from /home/nuno/workspace/depot_a/config.ru:1:in `new'
    from /home/nuno/workspace/depot_a/config.ru:1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you using ruby 1.8.x? It seems that you are using 1.9.x style hash notation, which 1.8.x can not decipher

Instead of

```
hash = { a: 1, b: 2}
```

you should use:

```
hash = { :a => 1, :b => 2 }
```

The problem is in `config/initializers/session_store.rb:11`, if you are still stuck, please post the code of this line.

Comment: Pretty sure the latest version of the book uses the new style :{)

Answer (score 1):

If you've followed Getting Started with Rails and are on Mac OS X Lion, run

```
rvm use --default 1.9.2
```

before running

```
rails server
```

Hope that helps.